# Unity Rigidbody move like Character Controller on collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I want to a blue ball moving like a figure.

in CharacterController, it was possible.

but in Rigidbody, object was stucked.

help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is too vague but this may help:*

If your expected behavior can't be achieved through unity physics then simply write your own.

Don't use rigidbody, instead use a collider with trigger (IsTrigger=true) and [OnCollisionEnter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigj6S0hMPOAhVGFMAKHUU-DzoQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.unity3d.com%2FScriptReference%2FCollider.OnCollisionEnter.html&v6u=https%3A%2F%2Fs-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com%2Fgen_204%3Fip%3D148.251.108.2%26ts%3D1471250820949117%26auth%3D6s5k245ac5d5x2s7a7ayryorqhdhtygj%26rndm%3D0.4796554658510579&v6s=2&v6t=18179&usg=AFQjCNGDVzSl83dOeAOt95qmWrMXs5Rczw&sig2=My3cAHIbGQqpMp7zCTs0nw&bvm=bv.129422649,d.d24) and [OnCollisionExit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi7257ehMPOAhULnRoKHfe_BuQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.unity3d.com%2FScriptReference%2FMonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html&usg=AFQjCNGztu5NsYaNq4TlUhXhBt0iUQX2kw&sig2=s6AgGTa-FaUlKwG6OEyM9w&bvm=bv.129422649,d.d24) or OnColliderEnter to detect physical collisions and use FixedUpdate to calculate your desired movement behaviour.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   Debug.Log(collision.contacts[0].normal);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   //use time.fixedDeltaTime
}
```